# In place modification of a line read in a file using perl script

Tags: regex, perl, scripting

I have a file which i pass as `ARGV[0]` or parameter to my perl script. This file contains list of files i will read which and modify lines in individual files. I want to modify these in-place and not write to a new file.

code is something like this:-

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use FindBin;
 use English;
 use File::Path;

 my $list=$ARGV[0];
 open(my $WAY,'<:encoding(UTF-8)',$list) or die("could not open list file");
 foreach my $file(<$WAY>){
 chomp($file);
 open(my $ASCII,''<:encoding(UTF-8)',$file) or die("could not open list file");
 foreach my $line (<$ASCII>){
 chmop($line);
 #####Here I do important stuff as per business requirement
 ## Now a array @coloumns stores all the values by which i need to 
 ### replace this read line.
 ##This array element needs to be joined by ',' so basically i want
 ##to replace read line in-place by join(",",@coloumns,"\n");
 }
 }
```

How can i achieve the same ?

Comment: Read all lines into a data structure first, close the file, re-open it for writing, and write out your modifications. Or mv the file to a tmp file first, and do it line at a time.

Comment: I am not looking to make a temp file , can you provide an example how to do it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've included both ways: with a temp file and using an array below.

But, you really *do* want to use the temp file method as it is *atomic*. With the array method, if the system crashes during the writeback, your file will be *trashed*. The temp file method is guaranteed to be atomic and your file will *not* be trashed if there is a crash.

So, what is your objection to the temp file?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use FindBin;
use English;
use File::Path;

my $list=$ARGV[0];
open(my $WAY,'<:encoding(UTF-8)',$list) or
    die("could not open list file -- '$list'\n");
foreach my $file (<$WAY>) {
    chomp($file);
    dotmp($file);
}
close($WAY);

sub dotmp
{
    my($file) = @_;
    my($oline);

    open(my $INPUT,'<:encoding(UTF-8)',$file) or
        die("could not open input file -- '$file'\n");

    my($tmp) = $file . ".TMP";
    open(my $OUTPUT,'>:encoding(UTF-8)',$tmp) or
        die("could not open output file\n");

    foreach my $line (<$INPUT>){
        chomp($line);

        #####Here I do important stuff as per business requirement
        ## Now a array @coloumns stores all the values by which i need to
        ### replace this read line.
        ##This array element needs to be joined by ',' so basically i want
        ##to replace read line in-place by join(",",@coloumns,"\n");

        $oline = join(",",@coloumns);

        print($OUTPUT $oline,"\n");
    }

    close($INPUT);
    close($OUTPUT);

    # NOTE: this is _atomic_ -- even if the system crashes, you'll either get
    # the whole contents before or after but _never_ a partial mashup
    rename($tmp,$file) or
        die("unable to rename '$file' -- $!\n");
}

sub doarray
{
    my($file) = @_;
    my($oline);
    my(@array);

    open(my $INPUT,'<:encoding(UTF-8)',$file) or
        die("could not open input file -- '$file'\n");

    foreach my $line (<$INPUT>){
        chomp($line);

        #####Here I do important stuff as per business requirement
        ## Now a array @coloumns stores all the values by which i need to
        ### replace this read line.
        ##This array element needs to be joined by ',' so basically i want
        ##to replace read line in-place by join(",",@coloumns,"\n");

        $oline = join(",",@coloumns);

        push(@array,$oline);
    }

    close($INPUT);

    open(my $OUTPUT,'>:encoding(UTF-8)',$file) or
        die("could not open output file\n");

    # NOTE: if the system crashes while doing this, the file will be corrupted
    foreach $oline (@array) {
        print($OUTPUT $oline,"\n");
    }

    close($OUTPUT);
}
```

Comment: for the array method, we can at least reduce the number of writes to the file: `print $OUTPUT join("\n", @array), "\n";`

Comment: @glennjackman The array method was just for completeness but _not_ recommended for the reasons I mentioned. Even if it could be done in a _single_ [large] write, it's still a hazard. It's been a while since I've benched it, but because a perl `foreach` iterator is so fast and the speed of `perlio`, the loop is probably faster than the `join` because it doesn't have to create an intermediate [implicit] scalar. The `join` will still get splayed out in `perlio` [which will cut it up into smaller `write(2)` calls], so more of a [syntactic] convenience than a speedup.

Comment: @glennjackman I've had to at various times. fc22's perl broke my scripts [their fault]. I also do metaprogramming in perl on my perl by installing a filter (see `perldoc -f require`). I use it like `cpp` for C to add/elide debug code. That _has_ to be fast [it's overhead during loading], and I benched and found out that `while ($x = <IN>) { chomp($x); push(@a,$x); }` beats `@a = <IN>; chomp(@a);` every time.

Comment: Since this is a (good) general recommendation, why not use a more robust naming for the temp file?  For example via `use File::Temp qw(tempfile)`, or such. [File::Temp](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Temp.html) is a core module.

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR:** aet's comment is probably your best bet.  Text files are generally poor candidates for true in-place editing.

## The Rope you're looking for:

If you open the file with a `+<` (read and write) mode instead of just the `<` (read) mode, you can use `tell` and `seek` to move around the file and write to your heart's content.

### Why it's a bad idea:

Rare is the change you may want to make to a *text file* that does not change the number of bytes consumed.  If your new text is longer, as would happen by adding commas, you'll overwrite data that had followed the original data.  If it's shorter, you'll have some of the former bytes still lying about.

### That is why programs that make "changes" to text files actually "rewrite" them.

Even Perl's `-i` command line switch actually uses the temp file technique recommended by Craig Estey.

Comment: I like the insight provided here. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Tie::File](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::File) may be a bit overkill, but it does what you want. To build `@contents`, I just split the original line on whitespace.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Tie::File;

my $list = $ARGV[0];

open my $way, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $list or die $!;

while (my $file = <$way>){
    chomp $file;
    tie my @contents, 'Tie::File', $file or die $!;

    for (@contents){
        my @columns = split /\s+/, $_;
        s/.*/join ', ', @columns/e;
    }

    untie @contents;
}
```

Example file that was specified in the argument file:

```
one two three
1 2 3
a b c
```

Output:

```
one, two, three
1, 2, 3
a, b, c
```

Comment: Use of ties seems to have [fallen out of fashion](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic::Policy::Miscellanea::ProhibitTies) in the Perl 5 era.

Comment: I personally don't use them, but I dabbled with Tie::File a couple of years ago. Although I didn't stick with it for the at-the-time project, the idea still stuck

Comment: @tjd ties have limited uses in things like key/value pair DBMs (e.g. Berkeley DB). I did a few, back in the day, just to get my feet wet. IMO, they can be useful in tracking down bugs. If you're getting a variable corrupted, somewhere, by something, and can't use the debugger (e.g. corruption only occurs after N days in a live production system and have too many places where it gets changed to add check code everywhere), you can tie the variable and have the underlying class do whatever complex watchpoint code you want.